# Javascript. Формат переменной

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, svg

У меня два вопроса: 
1) Я передаю в функцию circle: number - начальная позиция круга, final - конец круга, selector - объект, c которым я буду работать, найденный по селектору.
Получается так, что всем четырём круга передаются цифры, и они заполняются в правильном соотношении, но текст не выводится в трёх следующих кругах, а в первом выводится. 
**Вопрос:** почему в первом круге всё выводится, а в следующих нет?

2) Я сделал анимацию с помощью .progressbar__thumb {transition: stroke-dasharray 0.05s linear} в СSS , а в JS таймер интервальный, который срабатывает раз в 50 миллисекунд, также как и transition.
В итоге получается заполнение круга не таким плавным, как хотелось бы.
**Вопрос:**  возможно сделать заполнение как-то плавнее?

```js
function setProgress(percent, selector__circle) {
  let circle = document.querySelector(selector__circle);
  let total = Math.PI * circle.r.baseVal.value;
  circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${total*percent/100} ${total*(1-percent/100)*2}`;
  document.querySelector('svg text').innerHTML = '<tspan>' + percent.toFixed(0) + '</tspan>%';
}

function circle (number, final, selector) {
 let timer = setInterval(function () {
  setProgress(number, selector);
  number += 1;
  if (number == final) {
   clearInterval(timer);
  }
 }, 50);
}

circle(0, 91, '.progress__container:nth-child(1) .progressbar__thumb');
circle(0, 81, '.progress__container:nth-child(2) .progressbar__thumb');
circle(0, 71, '.progress__container:nth-child(3) .progressbar__thumb');
circle(0, 91, '.progress__container:nth-child(4) .progressbar__thumb');
```

```css
.cards__progress__bar {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-around;
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 80px;
}

.progress__container {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.progressbar__track {
 fill: transparent;
 stroke: #ededed;
 stroke-width: 2px;
}

.progressbar__thumb {
 fill: transparent;
 stroke: #ff0036;
 stroke-width: 2px;
 transition: stroke-dasharray 0.05s linear;
 transform-origin: center;
 transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.progressbar text {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.progressbar text tspan {
 fill: #ff0036;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards__progress__bar">

     <div class="progress__container">
       <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
         <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
         <circle class="progressbar__thumb" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
         <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle></text>
       </svg>
     </div> <!-- .progress__container -->

     <div class="progress__container">
       <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
         <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
         <circle class="progressbar__thumb" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
         <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle></text>
       </svg>
     </div> <!-- .progress__container -->

     <div class="progress__container">
       <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
         <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
         <circle class="progressbar__thumb" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
         <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle></text>
       </svg>
     </div> <!-- .progress__container -->

     <div class="progress__container">
       <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
         <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
         <circle class="progressbar__thumb" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
         <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle></text>
       </svg>
     </div> <!-- .progress__container -->

    </div> <!-- .cards__progress__bar -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

могу лишь ответить почему у Вас только в первом кругу заполняется текст.
потому что в строке

```
document.querySelector('svg text').innerHTML = '<tspan>' + percent.toFixed(0) + '</tspan>%';
```

каждый раз меняется текст одного и того самого элемента. Это происходит потому что `querySelector` находит ***один*** ближайший ему найденный селектор в **DOM**, то есть в Вашем случае один и то же `'svg text'` 4 раза подряд.

Answer (score 0):

**Вопрос:** возможно сделать заполнение как-то плавнее?
**Ответ:** да, возможно, нужно использовать requestAnimationFrame вместо таймера.

```js
function circle (number, final, selector) {
    let myReq = null;
    circleStep();
    function circleStep() {
        setProgress(number, selector);
        number += 1;
        if (number == final) {
            cancelAnimationFrame(myReq);
        }
        myReq = requestAnimationFrame(circleStep);
    }
}
```